# Python 2.7 Tkinter: How would I config the shape under the mouse with key press

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Basically I have a program that creates circles on a canvas with slider widgets getting the rgb values and a text box to the side showing the hexadecimal value of said color what I am wanting to do is get this to where if the user didnt like the color they can hover over the shape and press the key 'r' to change the color of the shape directly under the mouse cursor to the shape in which is now made with the sliders if they changed it.
Code so far:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title('Hexadecimal Explorer')

red_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar() 
red_intvar.set(127)
blue_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar() 
blue_intvar.set(127)
green_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar()
green_intvar.set(127)

def color_changed(new_intval):
    editor.insert(Tkinter.END, '#' + hexstring(red_intvar) + hexstring(green_intvar) + hexstring(blue_intvar) + '\n')
    editor.see(Tkinter.END)
    color = '#' + hexstring(red_intvar) + hexstring(green_intvar) + hexstring(blue_intvar)
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, background='#FFFFFF')
canvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=4, column=2)

red_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, variable=red_intvar, 
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,   
                       label='Red', command=color_changed)
red_slider.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

blue_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, variable=blue_intvar, 
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,   
                       label='Blue', command=color_changed)
blue_slider.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

green_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, variable=green_intvar,  
                         orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                         label='Green', command=color_changed)
green_slider.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=Tkinter.E)

text = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Drag slider \nto adjust\ncolor code.')
text.grid(row=0, column=0)

editor = Tkinter.Text(root, width=10)
editor.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=4)

def down(event):
    global startx, starty 
    startx = event.x 
    starty = event.y
shapes = []
def up(event):
    tk_color_string = color(red_intvar, green_intvar, blue_intvar)
    r = (startx-event.x)**2 + (starty-event.y)**2  # Pythagorean theorem
    r = int(r**.5)                                 # square root to get distance
    new_shape = canvas.create_oval(startx-r, starty-r, startx+r, starty+r,
                                fill=tk_color_string, outline='#000000')
    shapes.append(new_shape)

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', down)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', up)

def recolor(event):
    startx = event.x
    starty = event.y
    tk_color = color(red_intvar, green_intvar, blue_intvar)
    canvas.itemconfig(event.widget.find_closest(startx, starty), fill=tk_color)
canvas.bind('r', recolor)

def hexstring(slider_intvar):
    slider_int = slider_intvar.get()
    slider_hex = hex(slider_int)
    slider_hex_digits = slider_hex[2:] 
    if len(slider_hex_digits)==1:
        slider_hex_digits = '0' + slider_hex_digits 
    return slider_hex_digits

def color(r,g,b):
    rx=hexstring(r)
    gx=hexstring(g)
    bx=hexstring(b)
    return '#'+rx+gx+bx
root.mainloop()
```

I feel like this is an easy fix, but have research the issue and cant find much on it, thank you for your time.

Comment: What's your question? It seems like you're asking us to implement this for you. Is there a specific part of the problem you're struggling with?

Comment: The actual problem appears to be "... But when I press R, instead of the color of an oval changing, nothing happens at all".

Comment: The problem Byran is that I cant seem to get the circle to change colors and I don't know how to find the shape(ovals) in the canvas without the mouse click and since I want the user to be able to press a button to do this I would see clicking more of a problem since clicking makes a new shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
canvas.bind('r', recolor)
```

Here is the problem. Ordinarily, Canvas objects never receive keyboard focus, so binding keyboard shortcuts to them has no effect.

You can force the canvas to have focus using `focus_set`. A logical place to do this would be in your mouse click callback.

```
def down(event):
    global startx, starty 
    startx = event.x 
    starty = event.y
    canvas.focus_set()
```

---

Alternatively, try binding to the root window. This will change the contents of the `event` object though, so you will need to refer to `canvas` directly on the `itemconfig` line, and do a little extra arithmetic to find the position of the mouse relative to the canvas.

```
def recolor(event):
    startx = event.x - canvas.winfo_x()
    starty = event.y - canvas.winfo_y()
    tk_color = color(red_intvar, green_intvar, blue_intvar)
    canvas.itemconfig(canvas.find_closest(startx, starty), fill=tk_color)
root.bind('r', recolor)
```

Comment: Thank you this helped to fix the problem I did however use another binding to the motion of the mouse to get the startx and starty so the position of the mouse is always known, Thank you for your help

Comment: binding to the root window will affect _every_ widget, including text and entry widgets. The better solution is to simply give the canvas keyboard focus.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I considered that, but I decided against it because I thought dragging the sliders around would cause the canvas to lose focus again, which would be inconvenient. But now I see that sliders don't steal focus in this way, so `focus_set` should work fine. Edited.